# What are operations that the New Development Bank can't carry out because of the Russian-Ukraine war sanctions?

Tags: russian-federation, brics

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_Development_Bank

> On March 3, 2022, in response to the Russia-Ukraine War, the New
> Development Bank announced that it put new transactions with Russia on
> hold.[21] Even though the NDB quickly cut ties with Russia, Fitch
> Ratings still downgraded the NDB from stable to negative on its
> Long-Term Issuer Default scale.[22]

What are operations that the New Development Bank can't carry out because of the Russian-Ukraine war sanctions? This excerpt mentions that the NDB put new transactions with Russia on hold, it doesn't mention what other complications the sanctions has in its operations. Can Russia fund, vote, and do other things within the bank or is Russia now completely excluded? What are other things the bank cannot do because of the sanctions?